# Recursive method in class producing endlessly repeating value

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

sorry for beginner question here.

I'm trying to implement an **insert** method for a linked list class, using recursion, as seen in the code below.
However, when I try it, I get back a list that infinitely repeats the value I want to insert.

**e.g.**
1st node is 'a',
2nd node is 'b',
3rd node is 'c'.

If I used the code to insert 'd' as a new 3rd node, I'd get "abdddddddd...." ad infinitum.

Would really appreciate some advice on what caused this behavior.

```
class linked_list():


    def __init__(self, node):
        self.node = node


    def insert_at_index (self, index, value, node=None, current_index=0):
        def insert_recur(index, new_node, node, current_index):
            if current_index == index:
                node.next_node = new_node
                new_node.next_node = node.next_node
                return None
            else:
                return insert_recur(index, new_node, node.next_node, current_index+1)
        
        new_node = Node(value)
        if index == 0:
            new_node.next_node = self.node
            self.node = new_node
            return
        else:
            node = self.node 
            insert_recur(index, new_node, node, current_index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if current_index == index:
    node.next_node = new_node
    new_node.next_node = node.next_node
    return None
```

After assigning `node.next_node = new_node`, the old value of `node.next_node` has been lost.  The assignment that follows, `new_node.next_node = node.next_node`, is equivalent to `new_node.next_node = new_node`.  So `new_node` becomes its own successor.

Try reversing the order of the assignments:

```
if current_index == index:
    new_node.next_node = node.next_node
    node.next_node = new_node
    return None
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thanks so much! Marked as answer :D